# finding code that change excel value into integer linear programming formula

Tags: python, excel, open-source, linear-programming

I am finding code that using excel as input and change the excel value into formula of integer linear programming which will be as the input of a solver(python code write by myself). It is good if the code is in python. But I hardly find that resources or courses about that. If anyone know about that. Please tell me. Thanks!

I searched online. I just found code that solve problems of integer linear programming and cannot found code that generate formula which I tried to find.

Comment: round() may be what you  need, difficult without any example to see.